# top position not working in ie

Tags: css, internet-explorer, css-position

I'm having a problem with my top position not working in ie11 and below. I have 4 navigation icons that should be positioned in the middle of the top, left, bottom and right sides of the homepage. Any ideas on how this code could be conflicting in ie?

```
.section-nav .nav-top .hm-icon,
.section-nav .nav-right .hm-icon,
.section-nav .nav-bottom .hm-icon,
.section-nav .nav-left .hm-icon{
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      width: auto;
      height: auto;
      display: block;
      line-height: 50px;
      margin-top: -25px;
      margin-left: -25px;

}
```

Comment: Is there a live demo that can be accessed?

Comment: yes at www.gomiflight.com

Comment: Matters do work in FF and Chrome?